# Why AsyncRestTemplate in a spring doesn't has Interceptors like RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-web

I have one situation where I need to intercept the request and I need to set authorization header into that request.
So I got the solution that I can use interceptors to set that header but when I check **AsyncRestTemplate** then It doesn't have that property like RestTemplate.

Is there any specific reason to not include that property?

Answer (score 1):

The `AsyncRestTemplate` extends the `InterceptingAsyncHttpAccessor` abstract class, which exposes the method `setInterceptors`. So of course you can set Interceptors, just like you would do with the non async RestTemplate. Note that your interceptor needs to implement the `AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor` instead:

```
public class AsyncFooBarInterceptor implements AsyncClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<ClientHttpResponse> intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, AsyncClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        return null; // do your thing instead
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
asyncRestTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new AsyncFooBarInterceptor()));
```

Comment: AsyncRestTemplate which I using doesn't have the property 'setInterceptors'. It come's from spring-web-4.0.4.jar

Comment: So you're not using spring? @NIravModi

Comment: this is the definition of class AsyncRestTemplate extends AsyncHttpAccessor implements AsyncRestOperations

Comment: [This change](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/12969f62688b1e8863c57d2ed0960cd27fc625f9#diff-d368f2e9af2df1f1f7315c2dfbe23222) to make `AsyncRestTemplate` extend `InterceptingAsyncHttpAccessor` was made sometime between 4.2.4 and 4.3.5.